# Jquery select menu visibility issue

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm trying to create a second navigation menu for my responsive website. When a small screen accesses the site, a dropdown menu should appear instead of the full menu. I'm using to make this work but for some reason the select menu just doesn't seem to appear.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <nav class="container clearfix primary">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../about.html">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="../services.html">services</a></li>
            <li><a href="../partners.html">partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="../research.html" class="selected">research</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="extracts.html">Key Extracts & Findings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contents.html">Report Contents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="segments.html">Mobile VUI Segments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contributors.html">Participants & Contributors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bibliography.html">Bibliography</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="../contact.php">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//build dropdown
$("<select />").appendTo(".primary div");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");

// Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
$(".primary div ul li a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value"   : el.attr("href"),
        "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo("nav select");
});

//make responsive dropdown menu actually work
$("nav select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

});

Comment: That's because your select element doesn't have option elements!

Comment: Sorry I did not add all the code:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

 //build dropdown
 $("<select />").appendTo(".primary div");

 // Create default option "Go to..."
 $("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Go to..."
 }).appendTo("nav select");

 // Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
 $(".primary div ul li a").each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
   $("<option />", {
       "value"   : el.attr("href"),
      "text"    : el.text()
   }).appendTo("nav select");
 });

});

Comment: It still does not appear on the menu?

Comment: Your code works here http://jsfiddle.net/ey8gM/

Comment: Hmmm? I have no idea why it's not showing up. I'll try siv through the HTML & CSS again.